# How to query logstash indexes with .net elasticsearch client?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, nest

I'm trying to use NEST for searching through elastic search indexex that were created with logstash (basically logstash-*).

I have setup NEST with following code:

```
 Node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
 Settings = new ConnectionSettings(Node);
 Settings.DefaultIndex("logstash-*");
 Client = new ElasticClient(Settings);
```

this is how I try to get results:

```
var result = Client.Search<Logstash>(s => s
            .Query(p => p.Term("Message", "*")));
```

and I get 0 hits:
http://screencast.com/t/d2FB9I4imE

Here is an example of entry I would like to find:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.06.20",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "AVVtswJxpdkh1tFPP9S5",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "timestamp": "2016-06-20 14:04:55.6650",
    "logger": "xyz",
    "level": "debug",
    "message": "Processed command service method SearchService.SearchBy in 65 ms",
    "exception": "",
    "url": "",
    "ip": "",
    "username": "",
    "user_id": "",
    "role": "",
    "authentication_provider": "",
    "application_id": "",
    "application_name": "",
    "application": "ZBD",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-06-20T12:04:55.666Z",
    "host": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1466424295666
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1466424295666
  ]
}
```

I'm using 5.0.0-alpha3 version, and NEST client is alpha2 version atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of

```
...
"_type": "logs",
...
```

When you are doing query like yours it will hit `logstash` not `logs` type, because NEST infers type name from generic parameter. You have two options to solve this problem.

1. Tell NEST to map `Logstash` type to `logs` type whenever making
   request to elasticsearch, by setting this mapping in client's
   settings:

   ```
   var settings = new ConnectionSettings()
       .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Logstash), "logs");

   var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
   ```
2. Override default behaviour by setting type explicitly in request
   parameters:

   ```
   var result = Client.Search<Logstash>(s => s
       .Type("logs")
       .Query(p => p.Term("message", "*")));
   ```

   Also notice you sould use `message` not `Message` in term descriptor
   as you don't have such field in index. Second this is as far as I
   know wildcards are not supported in term query. You may want to use
   [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) instead.

Hope it helps.